# Are the Arduino sensors/components compatible with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to build my own irrigation system. Before I was thinking to do this using an Arduino UNO controller, however, I decided to switch to a Raspberry Pi 3, which suites my needs better.

What I got left are some humidity sensors, such as the one [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Soil-Moisture-Sensor/). Are these going to be compatible with the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Personally, I don't think there's really a reason to use a Raspberry Pi because that thing is an entire computer on its own. I usually use an Arduino as a data collector and a decision maker. If I wanted to work with a Raspberry Pi, I'd use it as a data displayer via wireless serial information being sent from the Arduino. However, that's just my person preference. There is a project called, [OpenSprinkler for Pi](http://rayshobby.net/ospi/) and that's really good if you want to utilize it as data collector and decision maker.

Comment: the things you need to look at are arduinos started off with 5V based things and the pi and many other boards/chips are 3.3v, the avrs (chips used in the arduino) also support or have family members that are 3.3v, so you have to be careful when you cross over that you are not trying to run a 5v design with 3.3v it might not work or if you get 5v into the peripheral that it isnt driving 5v into 3.3v I/O unless that I/O is 5v tolerant.

Answer (score 2):

The Soil Hygrometer Detection Module uses a simple comparator that is supposedly 3.3V compatible, so it will work with the RPi.